# Battery optimization whitelist doesn't work

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, battery-saver

I have an IntentService in my app that do some work in foreground mode. The code like this:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
   while (i < 100){
      task();
      i++;
   }
}

public void task(){
    //To do work and then
    try {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        }catch (InterruptedException exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I add my app in Battery optimization whitelist (Android 7.0), but when the screen goes out the intent service waits when the screen wakes up the intent service continues to work. Why the app doesn't work when the screen off?

Comment: whitelisting in battery Options is not enough in some devices (best example Huawei). There are also other Options, for example autorun. Autorun doesn´t suggest that it is needed for such case, but it is. You have to whitelist your app there too...

Comment: Opiatefuchs, thank you. My device Samsung Galaxy A5 how to add Autorun options programmatically?

Comment: Don´t know if Samsung Galaxy A5 has something like this. I have it on my Huawei devices. I think you have to look around in your menu Settings if there are also other Options....

Comment: Does it mean I can't do battery optimization for all devices? Users must do it themselves?

Comment: yes, sadly it means exactly this. For example, my Huawei Ascend Mate 7 has a Telephony Manager, here you have to do some Settings manually. It´s not possible to do it programmatically. You can just tell your users to be sure your app ist whitelisted on all Options. It´s like the Doze Mode since android MM....no Chance to handle it for developers.

Comment: But for this you need to know the settings of different phones well! It's impossible, there are a lot of phones! I can't believe it! ((

Comment: yep....but this depends on the user. I hope most of users will know their devices. And it´s the same like some third Party Task Managers, you will never know if there is installed one and kills your app. You can just give a hint....Maybe you can do a Little trick and use AlarmManager to fire in a certain period and enable the Service...but also it´s not guaranteed...

Comment: Opiatefuchs, thank you!